# what is "Import trace for requested module" and how to fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

this is my first time in the site, so sorry for bad question post, so, my app was working normally, no problems, today when i tried to run npm run dev (i didnt change anything just run it) i got this wierd error, that even the terminal wasnt enough to fit it , anyone have any idea ?

https://gist.github.com/Enkai0110/2336a8fe345f17cdd0221c4661a19785

i cleared browser history and cache, deleted the next. folder, but nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue often occurs when there's a mismatch between file or directory names in your imports and the actual file system. For example, importing `./MyModule` and `./mymodule` could cause such conflicts.

To resolve this, ensure your project's file and directory names match your `import` statements and the naming conventions are consistent throughout the project. Delete the `node_modules` and the `build` folders, then run `npm install` again to rebuild the project.

Comment: hello, thanks for your time, it turned out that i once changed my project directory path from the original one "/e/development/project" to "/e/Development/project" by fault, i renamed it and it worked now, thanks !